# Get values in Listbox with multi control

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Cannot get values in listbox when click true of checkbox

XAML

```
<ListBox Name="lbox_Diarios" Width="{Binding ElementName=dg_ListaCtbMov,Path=ActualWidth}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Margin="0,2">
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Name="txbDiarioCabs" Text="{Binding DiarioCabs}" />
             <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="cbDiarioMovs" ItemsSource="{Binding DiarioMovs}" />
             <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Name="cbxImportarMovs" Content="Importar" IsChecked="{Binding ImportarMovs}"  Checked="CheckBox_Checked" />
         </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Create simple class

```
    public class ListImportarMovs {
    public string DiarioCabs { get; set; }
    public List<string> DiarioMovs { get; set; }
    public bool ImportarMovs { get; set; }
}
```

After set load all list

```
    private void setLoadDiarios()
{
    List<string> diarios = new List<string>();
    ....

    foreach (.....)
        lbox_Diarios.Items.Add(new ListImportarMovs()
        {
            DiarioCabs = j.Name + ";" + j.NameID,
            DiarioMovs = diarios,
            ImportarMovs = false
        });

    ....
}
```

Well, i have one item checkbox, when user click an checkbox, event fire

```
//my problems... cannot get all values in item selected
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (Object selectedItem in lbox_Diarios.SelectedItems)
    MessageBox.Show( " ->" + (selectedItem as ListImportarMovs).DiarioCabs.ToString()+
        "  diarioM: " + (selectedItem as ListImportarMovs).DiarioMovs.ToString()); 

}
```

It's my problem, cannot get values a listbox when event fire...

Regards

Comment: In foreach you are using `lbox_Diarios.SelectedItems`, change it with `lbox_Diarios.SelectedItem`

Comment: How do I know the selected item of ComBobox?

Comment: Your ListImportarMovs class needs to declare another string property, e.g. `public string SelectedDiarioMov { get; set; }`. Then bind the ComboBox like `<ComboBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDiarioMov}" />`.

Comment: You can get the Selected Item of the combobox using the Selected Item of listbox itself. Once you have the Selected Item of listbox, just cast it to your class type and get the Selected Item of the combobox

Comment: As a note, the elements in the ItemTemplate do not need to have a Name.

Comment: @Aakanksha You don't have access to the ComboBox from a ListImportarMovs item.

Comment: @Clemens Yes that is what i meant. I thought there is a selected item binding in the ComboBox

Comment: It's possible show source example, please?

Comment: I can resolve, thanks Clement! Very simple... But no like one situation: When click checkbox fire alert: you need selected of list!! But when clicked checbox it's not implicit selected line listbox?